# Magento Skin from CDN

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

Hi i had this problems with my magento, it keeps getting a skin theme from an url.Below is an URL screen capture

[image]

```
http://cdn.glassesonline.com.my/skin/frontend/glassesonline/default/css/cloud-zoom.css
```

suppose to get it from

```
http://localhost/skin/frontend/glassesonline/default/css/cloud-zoom.css
```

how i can change this by code so that it doesn't get its skin from cdn. 
The problems persist event though i already change the secure and unsecure base URL in DB.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to System -> Web -> [ Unsecure | Secure ], you will see the options to set the base URLs for skin, among other things:

[image]